# Websocket return from function

Tags: javascript, websocket

im trying to use websockets for my application

```
function Connector()
{
  this.protocol = "bla";
  this.socket   = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org", this.protocol);
}

Connector.prototype.emit = function()
{
  this.socket.send('abc');
}
```

For me it is possible to call:

```
var con = new Connector();
con.emit();
```

from my Browsers console but from source code i get the following error message

```
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn 't You wait for the right value of `readyState` ?

```
function Connector(wsurl) {
    this.protocol = "bla";
    this.socket = new WebSocket(wsurl, this.protocol);
}
Connector.prototype.emit = function(msg) {

    var self = this;

    (function _waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (self.socket.readyState === 1) {
                console.log("Connection is made")
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback();
                }
                return;

            } else {
                console.log("wait for connection...")
                _waitForSocketConnection(callback);
            }
        }, 5);
    })(function() {
        console.log("message sent!!!");
        self.socket.send(msg);
    });
}


var con = new Connector("ws://echo.websocket.org");
con.emit('abc');
//or even worst
new Connector("ws://echo.websocket.org").emit('def');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546424/how-to-wait-for-a-websockets-readystate-to-change

Comment: yeah.. `console.log("message sent!!!");` is not exactly in the right place anyway ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you waiting for the `.onopen`  function to be called ?  you are supposed to send message on a websocket only after the connection is established.  you can try something like

```
    function Connector() {
        this.protocol = "bla";
        this.socket   = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org", this.protocol);
        this.connected = false;
    }
    Connector.prototype.emit = function() {

        if(this.connected) {
            try {
                this.socket.send('abc');
                return true;
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log('Error' + err.message);
                return false;
            }       
        }
        else {
            console.log('CRITICAL Error No WS');
            return false;
        }
    }

    con.socket.onopen = function() {
        console.log("webSocket Connected");
        con.connected = true;
        //send message here
        con.emit();
    };
    con.socket.onclose = function(e) {
        //closed
        con.connected = false;
    };
    con.socket.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error",e);
    };
    con.socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        //msg
    }
```

UPDATED CODE

```
function Connector(protocol, cB){
    var self = this,
        this.protocol = protocol,
        this.socket   = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org", this.protocol),
        this.connected = false;    

    this.socket.onopen = function() {
        self.connected = true;
        cB();
    };

    this.socket.onclose = function(e) {
        self.connected = false;
        //closed, inform(event)
    };

    this.socket.onerror = function(e) {
        //error, inform(event)
    };

    this.socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        //msg, inform(event)
    }
}

Connector.prototype.emit = function(msg) {
    if(this.connected) {
        try {
            this.socket.send(msg);
            return true;
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('Error' + err.message);
            return false;
        }       
    }
    else {
        console.log('CRITICAL Error No WS');
        return false;
    }
}

var con = new Connector('blah',function() {
    con.emit('abc');
});
```

and the simplest case with out a constructor or any other events; Just simple/basic ws client

```
var socket   = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org", 'bla');
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send('msg');
};
```

Comment: much better for the problems at the "beginning", but what if he calls emit() after the connection died?

Comment: @Gavriel :  i tried to in-corporate that quickly... thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Oxi doesn't is seems a really bad idea to set onXXX methods from the instance???...  you should write em for every instance...repeating even all the setting on _connected_ that should be definitely be private.... not only, you should write em AFTER creating a instance!!!...

Comment: @Oxi ...ohhh dude....  thanks for the down vote... instead of having a constructive discussion... you just ran away with a click.I bet it`s not the first time You miss the chance to learn something... Good luck!!!

Comment: @fedeghe : I have updated my answer. added two more code sample

Comment: @fedeghe : corrected the down vote mistake :) . Thanks, it was good one

Comment: @Oxi: great, I'm really happy you got it... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the socket to connect first. The Websocket constructor is non-blocking, which means that when you create a new Websocket, it connects in the background and your code continues. You need to set a `onopen` attribute on your Websocket to a callback that will get executed when the Websocket connects.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/WebSockets) you can see how it's done what events you can listen for.